# How to show custom dialog at Center Vertical

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

See the screen shot the dialog is not showing center vertically and unexpected margin

[image]

I have tried many example but no one solve this.
please refer to screen shot so you will understand very easy,what my problem is.
"As you see - Dialog appear with unexpected margin"

i have also try this

> **Window window = dialog.getWindow();
>                   window.setLayout(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
>                   AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>                   window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);**

java code is -

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogforgot_password);
            final EditText et_emailforgot = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.et_EnterMail);
            final Button bt_SubmitForgotPass = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_SubmitForgotButton);
            final TextView ForgotHeading = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_forgotpasswordHeading);
            final TextView PleaseEnterurMail = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_Enteruremail);
            et_emailforgot.setTypeface(Lato_Regular);
            PleaseEnterurMail.setTypeface(Lato_Regular);
            ForgotHeading.setTypeface(Lato_Bold);
            bt_SubmitForgotPass.setTypeface(Lato_Bold);
            dialog.show();
```

and my XML file is as Follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_windowcorner"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_headingcorner"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/RLForgot">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgotpasswordHeading"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Enter Your Registered Email id"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_Enteruremail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RLForgot"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/et_EnterMail"
        android:hint="Enter Your Email Id Here"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner_background"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Enteruremail"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:background="@drawable/signin_btn"
        android:textColor="@color/signinlogcolor"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/bt_SubmitForgotButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_EnterMail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use AppCompatDialog instead.

Comment: @Kishor please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what my problem is. "As you see - Dialog appear with unexpected margin"

it is called `Dialog` **title**  Use **`dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`**
 to remove title from `Dialog` like below `code`

Try this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);    
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogforgot_password);
```

Comment: Thanks,Working Fine

Comment: @Kishor happy to help you

Answer (score -1):

> There isn't any unexpected margin in your dialog

Your dialog is already aligned center vertically. Because you have the title bar, it seems off.

Put

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

after the dialog initialization